# Regex for leave blank text field else enter only valid detail

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

I want regex for checking text field  string ,for two conditions in only one regex, A user can leave text field full blank or enter valid numbers/alphabets/mobile number only.

please reply me soon I tried more ways.

Comment: show what have you tried.

Comment: @"^[\\s]*$|^[0-9]*$"

Comment: @"^[\\s]*$|[A-Za-z]+[[\\s][A-Za-z]+]*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@"^[\s]*$|^[0-9]*$" //regex for either space or number
@"^[\s]*$|[A-Za-z]+[[\s][A-Za-z]+]* //regex either space or alphabate